# Remote access to NAS not working

Tags: nas, port-forwarding, remote-access

I recently bought a **Synology DS412+** and am trying to set it up for remote access. Currently I'm trying to be able to access the DSM tool.

My home setup is as follows:

- The internet connects to a Sagem Webr@cer (VDSL modem + router). This router (**192.168.1.1**) operates in the 192.168.1.x range.
- Via cable, a second router Linksys E1000 is connected. This router (**192.168.2.2**) operates in the 192.168.2.x range.
- The NAS is linked by cable (twice) to this router, and has the fixed IP addresses **192.168.2.18** and **192.168.2.19**. I'm trying to set up the remote connection via the 192.168.2.19 address.

I registered a xxxxx.synology.me DDNS address, and it correctly resolves to my home IP address. I forced a refresh of my IP, and the DDNS was changed within minutes.
When I enter either the IP or DDNS address in my browser bar, the page does not load. However, when I open this URL from within my home network, I get my top router (192.168.1.1) configuration page. If I open that page up to remote access, I also get this config page when accessing from remote (which is a bad idea, but it proves that the DDNS is not at fault here).

So I assume there is an issue with my port forwarding on the top router. However, I am unsure how to correctly set up port forwarding between different routers. The ports I'm trying to forward are 5000, 5001 and 80.

Am I supposed to forward the ports to the second router (which then subsequently forwards the port to the NAS), or can I configure the top router to directly forward the port to the NAS?
I already tried both and neither worked, but maybe I'm missing something.

I tried setting it up via DSM and manually, but neither method worked for me. I think I'm missing some key piece of knowledge about a multi-router setup to correctly set this up.

Can anyone shed some light on the situation? If something is unclear please feel free to ask.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on how the two routers are connected, which is not clear to me at the moment. Is there a cable between the two? If so, which side of eac router is connected, the public or the private one? Also, can you pls explain why you need 2 routers?

Comment: They're connected by cable (it is mentioned, but maybe not obvious :)) What do you mean by public/private? I used to have only the linksys but I switched ISP and needed a VDSL modem, thus I got the Sagem. However, the Sagem makes a mockery of my internal network, so the Linksys is still in use because I needed a switch, and because it manages my internal network better than the Sagem can. Also, it has better wireless antennae than the Sagem.

Comment: Important to note: all machines are connected to the linksys router (some wireless, some by cable). The Sagem is only used for the VDSL communication. But the network itself is OK, I can stream between machines in many different setups. This is the first time I'm tryiong to get a connection past the Sagem router.

Comment: I should probably mention that I purchased the same NAS device Synology DS412+ and had nothing but issues with the unit.   The software could find the NAS sometimes, but other times it could not..   I think I may have had a defective unit, but regardless the whole setup process was far too complicated compared to any other NAS device i've deployed (20 to 30 devices deployed over the years).   I just want a simple web interface I can log into without some stupid piece of proprietary software in between.

Comment: As far as in-browser interfaces go, I haven't seen anything smoother than DSM. It just runs seamlessly. I haven't tried it remotely, though I suspect that any slowness that occurs only when remote has more to do with your ISP and the connection quality instead of the NAS itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to fix it. As suggested, I gutted my second router and disabled its DHCP server, so it functions purely as a switch.

That was not the solution, however. Apparently my ISP has ports 5000 and 5001 blocked. I Set my port forwarding from port 80 externally to port 5000 internally and now it works.

I'll check to see if I can use another port so it doesn't conflict with other services on the NAS, but it's good to see it working, now I know where to look.